# Why alarms in "To-do" applications are shown as notification

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am not sure whether my understanding about alarms is wrong, so I thought of posting this question. I keep forgetting tasks so I thought of installing the best "To-Do" android app. What I simply wanted from the application is this:

If I want to set a reminder, say on May 19th 2013, at 9.00 A.M and I want a a loud alarm that will keep ringing until I dismiss it or snoop.

Every famous app that I tried (Astrid, Wundrelist etc),  provide a reminder feature to be associated with Tasks, but these reminders to go Notification area. Some of the "to-do" apps takes the reminder date/time as alarms, but they again send these alarms as notifications. The problem with notification is that, it only makes a very simple sound (as if a message has arrived), that too only once. I want these reminders to ring as alarms not as notification. Do you know any apps that does this?. For example, the alarm that we can set in clock.( but clock doesn't provide a specific date/time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Astrid has this functionality. Add a task by giving it a title and then clicking ADD A DUE DATE if you wish. This opens a page where you can tap a due date + time. Click OK after making the necessary changes. Click the blue + sign on the right to add the task to your list.

Now tap the task to edit it - Scroll down if you need to and select DETAILS and then REMIND WHEN DUE & OVERDUE

Choose the options as you see fit and ensure that the RING/VIBRATE TYPE is set to UNTIL I DISMISS ALARM.

Click ADD AN ALARM and choose when you want to be reminded.

To avoid this rigmarole in the future, you can choose to set by default that reminders should ring constantly until you dismiss them. Click SETTINGS > NEW TASK DEFAULTS > DEFAULT RING/VIBRATE and then select UNTIL I DISMISS ALARM

Also see REMINDER SETTINGS where you can choose a ringtone of choice.

Comment: I tried this, but it is still a notification that gets notified repeatedly unless I dismiss it. It doesn't sound like an alarm.

Comment: Choose the ringtone of your choice to make it sound like an alarm, Pradeep.